# Insert a div to wrap other divs with JavaScript generated HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json

If I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        var agents = [];
        $.getJSON('js/agents.json', function(a) {
            $.each(a.agents, function(b, c) {
                var content = 
                '<div class="status-card">' +
                '<div class="agent-details">' +
                '<span class="agent-name">' + c.name + '</span>' +
                '<span class="handling-state">' + c.callStatus + '</span>' +
                '<span class="handling-time">' + c.handlingTime + '</span>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="status-indicator"></div>' +
                '</div>'
                $(content).appendTo('#left');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

And say that rendered from the JSON data:

```
<div class="status-card">
    <div class="agent-details">
        <span class="agent-name">Castro Cook</span>
        <span class="handling-state">Idle</span>
        <span class="handling-time">06:32:09</span>
    </div>
    <div class="status-indicator"></div>
</div>
<div class="status-card">
    <div class="agent-details">
        <span class="agent-name">Amie Spencer</span>
        <span class="handling-state">On Call</span>
        <span class="handling-time">06:00:17</span>
    </div>
    <div class="status-indicator"></div>
</div>
```

I want to use this JS:

```
var slideSection = $('div[class^="agent-status-section-"]').hide(),
i = 0;
(function cycle() { 
    slideSection.eq(i).fadeIn(900)
        .delay(2000)
        .fadeOut(900, cycle);
    i = ++i % slideSection.length;
})();
```

To only show 1 `.status-card` div at a time and cycle through, so I need to wrap each `.status-card` like:

```
<div class="agent-status-section-1">
    <div class="status-card">
        .......
    </div> 
</div>
<div class="agent-status-section-2">
    <div class="status-card">
        .......
    </div> 
</div>
```

Note that I'm just keeping it simple, really I'd be wrapping every 10 `.status-card` divs.

I found the following that I could use, but I'd also need to increment the number at the end (`agent-status-section-1, agent-status-section-2`) each time it's inserted, how would I do that?

```
var d = $('.status-card');
for( var i = 0; i < d.length; i+=5 ) {
    d.slice(i, i+5).wrapAll('<div class="agent-status-section-1">');
}
```

Hope that makes sense! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can divide your index by five (after incrementing within the loop) to get the series 1, 2, 3, ... and use it to dynamically construct your wrapping HTML string.

**Edit:** You can inspect the HTML code now in the following demo; it works!

```js
var cards = $('.status-card'),
    i = 0
while (i < cards.length) {
    cards.slice(i, i += 5).wrapAll('<div class="agent-status-section-' + (i / 5) + '">');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="status-card">
    <div class="agent-details">
        <span class="agent-name">Castro Cook</span>
        <span class="handling-state">Idle</span>
        <span class="handling-time">06:32:09</span>
    </div>
    <div class="status-indicator"></div>
</div>
<div class="status-card">
    <div class="agent-details">
        <span class="agent-name">Amie Spencer</span>
        <span class="handling-state">On Call</span>
        <span class="handling-time">06:00:17</span>
    </div>
    <div class="status-indicator"></div>
</div>
<div class="status-card">
    <div class="agent-details">
        <span class="agent-name">Castro Cook</span>
        <span class="handling-state">Idle</span>
        <span class="handling-time">06:32:09</span>
    </div>
    <div class="status-indicator"></div>
</div>
<div class="status-card">
    <div class="agent-details">
        <span class="agent-name">Amie Spencer</span>
        <span class="handling-state">On Call</span>
        <span class="handling-time">06:00:17</span>
    </div>
    <div class="status-indicator"></div>
</div>
<div class="status-card">
    <div class="agent-details">
        <span class="agent-name">Castro Cook</span>
        <span class="handling-state">Idle</span>
        <span class="handling-time">06:32:09</span>
    </div>
    <div class="status-indicator"></div>
</div>
<div class="status-card">
    <div class="agent-details">
        <span class="agent-name">Amie Spencer</span>
        <span class="handling-state">On Call</span>
        <span class="handling-time">06:00:17</span>
    </div>
    <div class="status-indicator"></div>
</div>
<div class="status-card">
    <div class="agent-details">
        <span class="agent-name">Castro Cook</span>
        <span class="handling-state">Idle</span>
        <span class="handling-time">06:32:09</span>
    </div>
    <div class="status-indicator"></div>
</div>
<div class="status-card">
    <div class="agent-details">
        <span class="agent-name">Amie Spencer</span>
        <span class="handling-state">On Call</span>
        <span class="handling-time">06:00:17</span>
    </div>
    <div class="status-indicator"></div>
</div>
<div class="status-card">
    <div class="agent-details">
        <span class="agent-name">Castro Cook</span>
        <span class="handling-state">Idle</span>
        <span class="handling-time">06:32:09</span>
    </div>
    <div class="status-indicator"></div>
</div>
<div class="status-card">
    <div class="agent-details">
        <span class="agent-name">Amie Spencer</span>
        <span class="handling-state">On Call</span>
        <span class="handling-time">06:00:17</span>
    </div>
    <div class="status-indicator"></div>
</div>
<div class="status-card">
    <div class="agent-details">
        <span class="agent-name">Castro Cook</span>
        <span class="handling-state">Idle</span>
        <span class="handling-time">06:32:09</span>
    </div>
    <div class="status-indicator"></div>
</div>
<div class="status-card">
    <div class="agent-details">
        <span class="agent-name">Amie Spencer</span>
        <span class="handling-state">On Call</span>
        <span class="handling-time">06:00:17</span>
    </div>
    <div class="status-indicator"></div>
</div>
<div class="status-card">
    <div class="agent-details">
        <span class="agent-name">Castro Cook</span>
        <span class="handling-state">Idle</span>
        <span class="handling-time">06:32:09</span>
    </div>
    <div class="status-indicator"></div>
</div>
<div class="status-card">
    <div class="agent-details">
        <span class="agent-name">Amie Spencer</span>
        <span class="handling-state">On Call</span>
        <span class="handling-time">06:00:17</span>
    </div>
    <div class="status-indicator"></div>
</div>
<div class="status-card">
    <div class="agent-details">
        <span class="agent-name">Castro Cook</span>
        <span class="handling-state">Idle</span>
        <span class="handling-time">06:32:09</span>
    </div>
    <div class="status-indicator"></div>
</div>
<div class="status-card">
    <div class="agent-details">
        <span class="agent-name">Amie Spencer</span>
        <span class="handling-state">On Call</span>
        <span class="handling-time">06:00:17</span>
    </div>
    <div class="status-indicator"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the `1` in the string with the `i` variable:

```
var d = $('.status-card');
for( var i = 0; i < d.length; i+=5 ) {
    d.slice(i, i+5).wrapAll('<div class="agent-status-section-' + i + '">');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var d = $('.status-card');
j=0;
for( var i = 0; i < d.length; i+=5 ) {
j++;
    d.slice(i, i+5).wrapAll('<div class="agent-status-section-'+j+'">');
}
```

P.S. Do you really need different class?

Comment: Actually not for this to work, which I didn't realise. I will need it but thanks for the heads up!